# How to prove the same subgoals

Tags: coq, coq-tactic, coqide

I have two equal subgoals like this:

`prove_me (x::xs) = true`

---

`prove_me (x::xs) = true`

Proofs will be equals. How I can solve the second goal using the first one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot literally reuse the proof of one goal on another goal, but you can prove an auxiliary lemma:

```
assert (H : prove_me (x::xs) = true).
{ (* proof of result *) }
```

Then, you can use `H` to discharge the two subgoals once they show up.

Comment: I agree with you.But if we have not a very big proof. I mean the sequence of applying tactics it will be better to write
`1, 2 : tactic1; tactic2; ...; tacticN. `
Here 1 and 2 - goal numbers